# Writing java files in nativescript to use native java lib

Tags: java, android, nativescript, tns

How to and where to write my java files? I wrote mine in `platforms/android/com/tns` to use a native plugin `NewPipeExtractor` and it doesn't recognise the import of the lib and `java.lang.System` and the import of the `newpipenlib` it returns `undefined`. What should I do?

App.gradle

```
compile 'com.github.newpipeextractor'
```

Java file

```
 import org.schabi.newpipe.(some lib/class)
 import java.lang.System
```

error:

```
JS: ERROR TypeError: _co.createVideoView is not a function
JS: ERROR CONTEXT {
JS:   "view": {
JS:     "def": {
JS:       "nodeFlags": 33734657,
JS:       "rootNodeFlags": 33554433,
JS:       "nodeMatchedQueries": 0,
JS:       "flags": 0,
JS:       "nodes": [
JS:         {
JS:           "nodeIndex": 0,
JS:           "parent": null,
JS:           "renderParent": null,
JS:           "bindingIndex": 0,
JS:           "outputIndex": 0,
JS:           "checkIndex": 0,
JS:           "flags": 33554433,
JS:           "childFlags": 180225,
JS:           "directChildFlags": 49153,
JS:           "childMatchedQueries": 0,
JS:           "matchedQueries": {},
JS:           "matchedQueryIds": 0,
JS:           "references": {},
JS:           "ngContentIndex": null,
JS:           "childCount": 3,
JS:           "bindings": [],
JS:           "bindingFlags": 0,
JS:           "outputs": [],
JS:           "element": {
JS:             "ns": "",
JS:             "name": "ActionBar",
JS:             "attrs": [
JS:               [
JS:                 "",
JS:                 "title",
JS:                 "Yt Download"
JS:               ]
JS:             ],
JS:             "template": null,
JS:             "componentProvider": {
JS:               "nodeInd...
JS: ERROR Error: java.lang.NullPointerException: downloader is null
JS:     org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.Extractor.<init>(Extractor.java:34)
JS:     org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.stream.StreamExtractor.<init>(StreamExtractor.java:44)
JS:     org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.services.youtube.extractors.YoutubeStreamExtractor.<init>(YoutubeStreamExtractor.java:93)
JS:     org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.services.youtube.YoutubeService.getStreamExtractor(YoutubeService.java:95)
JS:     org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.StreamingService.getStreamExtractor(StreamingService.java:288)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
JS:     com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
JS:     java.lang.Object_vendor_119474_32_ClickListenerImpl.onClick(Unknown Source:10)
JS:     android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
JS:     androi...
JS: ERROR CONTEXT {
JS:   "view": {
JS:     "def": {
JS:       "nodeFlags": 33734657,
JS:       "rootNodeFlags": 33554433,
JS:       "nodeMatchedQueries": 0,
JS:       "flags": 0,
JS:       "nodes": [
JS:         {
JS:           "nodeIndex": 0,
JS:           "parent": null,
JS:           "renderParent": null,
JS:           "bindingIndex": 0,
JS:           "outputIndex": 0,
JS:           "checkIndex": 0,
JS:           "flags": 33554433,
JS:           "childFlags": 180225,
JS:           "directChildFlags": 49153,
JS:           "childMatchedQueries": 0,
JS:           "matchedQueries": {},
JS:           "matchedQueryIds": 0,
JS:           "references": {},
JS:           "ngContentIndex": null,
JS:           "childCount": 3,
JS:           "bindings": [],
JS:           "bindingFlags": 0,
JS:           "outputs": [],
JS:           "element": {
JS:             "ns": "",
JS:             "name": "ActionBar",
JS:             "attrs": [
JS:               [
JS:                 "",
JS:                 "title",
JS:                 "Yt Download"
JS:               ]
JS:             ],
JS:             "template": null,
JS:             "componentProvider": {
JS:               "nodeInd...
```

code with declaration and usage:

```
declare const org:any;

const Downloader = org.schabi.newpipe.Downloader;
const NewPipe =  org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.NewPipe;
const YoutubeStreamExtractor =  org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.services.youtube.extractors.YoutubeStreamExtractor;
const Stream = org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.stream;
const Localization = org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.utils.Localization;
const YouTube = org.schabi.newpipe.extractor.ServiceList.YouTube;

downloadVideoInit(){
  let extractor;
  extractor = YouTube.getStreamExtractor("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YQHsXMglC9A");
  extractor.fetchPage(); 
  extractor.getAudioStreams();
 }
```

for example of usage of lib go to [here](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipeExtractor/blob/dev/extractor/src/test/java/org/schabi/newpipe/extractor/services/youtube/YoutubeStreamExtractorDefaultTest.java#L54-L57)

Comment: Your java code should be written in a library project and compiled as an AAR, shall be place in your `App_Resources/android/libs` and then it should accessible at run time.

Comment: How to convert to AAR? Plus, can I access a native lib from the java file, and how do i kick start the java file?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are preferring Java file, most times it's easy and sufficient to access Java classes from JavaScript, all you have to do is to include the library in Gradle. To generate AAR you should have basic work experience with Android Studio.

Comment: I tried but then a consistent error arose whenever i live updated the app which said something like `_co.createVideo is not a function`.I had the impression that it didn't understand the java lib or something.

Comment: You have to share the code you tried, `_co.createVideo` sounds like an internal error within your code.

Comment: check modified question, it has the error you were looking for